# run one time only why?? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

run one time only why?? JavaScript

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table" id="tbl1">
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
            <td><button class="mvFirst">One</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Two</td>
                <td><button class="mvFirst">Two</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Three</td>
                <td><button class="mvFirst">Three</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**Scripts**

```
 // plugin : move tr(row) on click to first 
        $.fn.moveFirst = function () {
            debugger;
            var ele=$(this).closest('tr').clone();
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $(ele).prependTo('#tbl1');
        };
        $('.mvFirst').click(function () {
            debugger;
            $(this).moveFirst();
        });
```

Why that working one time after this didn't work , I need to solve that please